# Is there a way to use an if statement inside a map procedure?

Tags: list, dictionary, if-statement, command, netlogo

I want to update several values in a list called `list1` depending on the values in two other lists called `list2` and `list3`. Basically the values in `list2` determine which equation the model should use to update the values in `list1` and the values in `list3` are used in those equations.

A working example would be:

```
turtles-own [list1 list2 list3]

to setup
  clear-all
  setup_turtles
  reset-ticks
end

to setup_turtles
  create-turtles 10
  [
    set list1 n-values 20 [1]
    set list2 n-values 20 [0 + random 3]
    set list3 n-values 20 [-0.5 + random-float 1]
  ]
end

to go
  ask turtles[ update_list1 ]
  tick
end

to update_list1
  set list1 (map [[b c] ->
    if (b = 0) [ 1 + c ]
    if (b = 1) [ 1 - c ]
    if (b = 2) [ 1 - c / 2 ]
  ] list2 list3)
end
```

Netlogo tells me it expects a command within the `if` statement, which makes sense considering how the if function is built. I was wondering if they're is a workaround which could make that work.

I have tried to use the `ifelse-value` function instead of `if` in the update_list1 procedure and it works (see code below)

```
to update_list1
  set list1 (map [[b c] ->
    ifelse-value (b = 0) [ 1 + c ] [
      ifelse-value (b = 1) [ 1 - c ][
        1 - c / 2
      ] 
    ] 
  ] list2 list3)
end
```

However, later on I plan on having more than 3 different values in list2 and I would like to avoid multiple indentation resulting from calling `ifelse-value` several times in a row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Netlogo has the option to use more than one boolean for a single call of `ifelse` or `ifelse-value`. To do this, you need to put round brackets around the entire expression: `(ifelse-value boolean1 [ reporter1 ] boolean2 [ reporter2 ] ... [ elsereporter ])`.
This ensures that you don't have to work with nested `ifelse-value`'s

```
to update_list1
  set list1 (map [[b c] ->
    (ifelse-value
        b = 0 [ 1 + c ]
        b = 1 [ 1 - c ]
        b = 2 [1 - c / 2]
              [print "b is not one of the expected values"]
    ) 
  ] list2 list3)
end
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This solves it. I've just checked and it's actually shown on the Netlogo ifelse-value info page. I should have studied it in more details sorry. ^^

Comment: You can also simply call your own reporter from inside the map anonymous reporter, just FYI.